# Trouble compiling sfml with mingW32

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, sfml, mingw-w64

I am trying to install sfml and run it with mingW. This is the first time I use it so I was following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ljhpsdz8Ouo). I followed it step by step until the end, where he compiles a test script to check if it works, his does, mine doesn't.

I can't figure out why, but it seems to be a problem with the paths because the output says it can't find some files.

```
g++ -Isrc/include -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphicsC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphicsC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphicsC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-graphics: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphicsC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window    
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window    
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-window: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window    
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system    
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-system: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:7: link] Error 1
```

These are my files:
[image]

My Makefile:

```js
all: compile link

compile:
    g++ -Isrc/include -c main.cpp

link:
    g++ main.o -o main -L src/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

And the script I'm trying to run is the test script from the documentation. Note that this is my first time using Makefile, but the main.o file is created properly.

I hope someone can help me, it's probalby an installation mistake. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It seems like you have improper binaries for the compiler you are using. You should instead use pacman to install the proper binaries for your compiler and those would be placed in the system location where your compiler is on disk so you would not need to specify linker paths or include paths.

Comment: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-sfml?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-sfml?repo=mingw64) should be the correct package and `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sfml` is the install command from the mingw64 terminal

Comment: @drescherjm It outputs this error: 
```error: mingw-w64-x86_64-graphite2: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-graphite2-1.3.14-2-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]``` Y or n don't do anything, it never installs.

Comment: [https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2058](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2058)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this can be caused by using the improper compilers, on the SFML website it states:

[image: SFML Compiler Requirements]

If you download these compilers and add them to your path variable (being careful to remove what might already be there to avoid a conflict) I am willing to bet you will be on your way.

I might also suggest using CMake as it makes the whole 'makefile' process a bit easier. It is an extra step, but in the future it will serve you well as your project expands. I have written a tutorial on this subject [here](https://wfale.net/2023/01/02/sfml-c-and-windows-quick-guide-to-awesome-graphics/) if you would like to see how that might look in practice. Good luck and hope this helps!